# IRasterLayer to IFields

Tags: arcobjects, java

If I have a layer of `IRasterLayer` type how can I get the attribute table field values in ArcObjects?

```
IRasterLayer layer = (IRasterLayer) map.layer[0];
```

Comment: You're several lines short of a proper code snippet here. What have you attempted?

Comment: I want get raster attribute table field names.

Comment: For good or for bad, ArcObjects development relies on the ability to use the documentation. There are zillions of little code samples, linked together in the doc. GIS SE also uses a self-service model -- Coding questions here are expected to show an effort to solve the problem. One line of code doesn't show enough effort. Please [Edit] the question to include a type on map and explain how casting a Layer to IRasterLayer helps you toward your goal. Most of the time, documenting your problem adequately actually provides the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @Vince, you need to be reading and understanding what the help file is telling you. So you are interested in RasterLayer Class, well look at it's page [here](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcobjects/latest/net/webframe.htm#rasterlayer.htm), these are all the interfaces to this class and if you look a little deeper (i.e. scroll down!) you will see that this class implements an interface for using fields.

Below is some VBA code to help you get going:

```vb
Public Sub Test()
    Dim pMXD As IMxDocument
    Set pMXD = ThisDocument
    Dim pMap As IMap
    Set pMap = pMXD.FocusMap
    Dim pLayer As ILayer
    Set pLayer = pMap.Layer(0)
    Dim pRasterLayer As IRasterLayer
    Set pRasterLayer = pLayer
    Dim pTableFields As ITableFields
    Set pTableFields = pRasterLayer
    Debug.Print pTableFields.FieldCount ' How many fields
    Debug.Print pTableFields.Field(2).Name 'Field name at index 2
End Sub
```

*Note: in this code I assume your raster has an attribute table (i.e. it's an integer raster type).*